# Vertex AI quota limit error when current usage percentage is zero

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform

In the context of a personal project, Im trying to use Vertex AI to run a TFX pipeline to train a model using custom training, based on [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/gcp/vertex_pipelines_vertex_training). When I run the pipeline I get the error:

> com.google.cloud.ai.platform.common.errors.AiPlatformException: code=RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, message=The following quota metrics exceed quota limits: aiplatform.googleapis.com/custom_model_training_cpus

On the IAM quotas I have limit "1" for the resource "Custom model training CPUs for N1/E2 machine types per region", for all regions, and 0% current usage for each one of them. I even tried multiple regions and multiple types of machines (n1, e2, ...) and I alway get that quota limit error.

Can anyone explain why Im getting this quota error?

Comment: You can contact [Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing).

Comment: @JoseGutierrezPaliza Already did that. I only have basic support plan, so it was pretty much useless. Please dont tell me that users need to subscribe to a paid support plan in order just to try Vertex AI.

Comment: Same here. Since all machine types require at least 4 CPUs, there is just no way to use Vertex AI without paying for a support plan upgrade only to request an increase on quota limits. That is messed up to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

> On the IAM quotas I have limit "1" for the resource "Custom model training CPUs for N1/E2 machine types per region", for all regions, and 0% current usage for each one of them.

The default quotas for `aiplatform.googleapis.com/custom_model_training_cpus` are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/quotas#custom-trained_model_quotas), and their range is between 20 and 2,200, depending on the region. I'm not sure why your limit would be 1, but I believe that means you will not be able to use any machine types that use more than one vCPU, so you can't even use "n1-standard-2", even if your pipeline would only use one machine of type "n1-standard-2" for training.

One thing you can try is editing the quotas for your GCP project from the [quotas page](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/apis/api/aiplatform.googleapis.com/quotas) by selecting the quota(s) in the table and then clicking the "Edit quotas" button.

Comment: Thanks. I could not edit any quotas, I would have to pay for support just to even try to request for higher quotas. I simply gave up using GCP and moved to other and much better cloud provider.